# Creating custom Robolectric shadows in 2.2+

Tags: android, unit-testing, shadow, robolectric

I want to create a custom shadow object that will listen in to calls that i make on the real object, so that i can do test assertions on the shadow. I'm using Robolectric to run my tests but i keep getting this weird error:

```
org.fest.reflect.exception.ReflectionError: Unable to find method '$$robo$getData' in com.blah.SomeClass with parameter type(s) []
```

This is what i've tried:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void doSomething() {}
}
```

and then in my test directory, create:

```
@Implements(SomeClass.class) 
public class ShadowSomeClass {
    @Implementation public void doSomething() {throw new RuntimeException("hi");}
}
```

and then i try to bind it in my custom TestRunner, which extends `RobolectricTestRunner`

```
@Override
protected ShadowMap createShadowMap() {
    return super.createShadowMap()
            .newBuilder()
            .addShadowClass(ShadowSomeClass.class)
            .build();
}
```

and then in a test class, using my custom `TestRunner`, i write a unit test:

```
@Test
public void robolectricNotWork() {
    SomeClass subject = new SomeClass();
    ShadowSomeClass shad = shadowOf_(subject); // this is the offending line of error
}
```

and then i get the error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hey David, have you found a solution to your above question?

Comment: i have not, unfortunately. once i do get around to this again, i will let you know though. sorry for the inconvenience!